# How do I write a CV-Coalgebra in Idris2?

Tags: idris, recursion-schemes

In Haskell, I can write

```
data CoAttr f a
  = Automatic a
  | Manual (f (CoAttr f a))
```

but Idris doesn't seem to allow such fix-point types with `data`. They do work with `record`, i.e. I can write

```
record CoAttrWithoutAutomatic (f : Type -> Type) where
    constructor Manual
    out : f (CoAttrWithoutAutomatic f)
```

but there I can't have more than one variant if I understand right. Is there a solution?

Answer (score 2):

Got it – I missed the general form of defining data types:

```
data CoAttr : (f : Type -> Type) -> (a : Type) -> Type where
  Automatic : a -> CoAttr f a
  Manual : (f (CoAttr f a)) -> CoAttr f a

CVCoalgebra : (f: Type -> Type) -> (a: Type) -> Type
CVCoalgebra f a = a -> f (CoAttr f a)
```